# Fastest way to display first frame of the video file in the DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, video

What is the fast(est) way to display one frame of the video on the page?

I have an `<input type="file" />` for choosing a video file, and I am trying to display just the first frame out of it, as a preview, but FileReader seems to be too slow. I made a simple video preview with base64 logic, and it works fine with ~1mb file sizes, but for ~20mb+ videos there is a huge overload while the video file is being processed for the preview.

I'm wondering if there is any way to display it inside 
`<canvas>` or `<img>` without loading the whole file? Thanks!

Comment: the fastest way would be to store the first frame as a jpeg and display that.

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to go through a `FileReader` which will read the entire stream into memory.

Just use the File blob directly as source via `URL.createObjectURL()` and the browser will buffer the load which allows you to extract a frame faster (as well as using less memory).

Comment: Yes a blobURI should definitely be used here. Two small notes though: (1) By using the `loadedmetadata` event, you run out of the infinite loop problem without having to handle it yourself; and in modern browsers, you can even simply do `video.play().then(()=>...`.

Comment: (2) In this exact case, `URL.revokeObjectURL` will not *free up* as much memory as you think. BlobURI made from a File on the user's system are merely just direct pointer to the File on disk. Revoking it will just remove the pointer, hence ±nothing in memory. However, video preloading is really fast in this case, so you will indeed have some useless data in memory; but to let the browser know it can free it, you would have to reset the MediaElement's src.